# Can someone help me interpret these diagrams?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diagram

I am extremely new to electrical engineering, and I am using it for a personal project. I tried looking into circuit diagrams for a part(a pushbutton), and I don't recognize any of the symbols. Most of the resources I have found cover general circuit diagram symbols like diodes and switches. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

edit: The part is MPSA-22 E08-O-150
https://www.knitter-switch.com/eng/Series/17

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to name the product and add a link to the datasheet (and not an ad page).

Comment: Looks to me like it's a double-pole, double-throw non-shorting switch.  For the upper switch, the "slide" (whatever that is physically), connects the the C (common) to either 4 or 5, but never both at the same time.  A similar action applies to the bottom half, the other pole, of the switch.

Comment: the connection diagram would be clearer if the bottom half was flipped horizontally

Answer (score 1):

That datasheet is not entirely clear to me - I'd want to get the switch in hand and measure continuity between terminals before laying out a PC board.

It appears that with the button released terminals 6 and 4 are connected, as are 1 and 3.

With the button pressed, 6 and 5 are connected, and 1 and 2 are connected.

To me, the connector drawing doesn't really indicate that - the two arrows pointing in opposite directions are confusing.

Comment: I agree the drawing is confusing but based on the time-lag diagram, I believe you are correct. This shows 6-4 and 1-3 connections, then no connection, then 6-5 and 1-2 connections.